# using mysql database generating transaction numbers

Tags: php, mysql

In my ERP i generate the transaction numbers using php and mysql means i have table like below

```
........................................  
**tid**      **transactionnumber**

1             TRNUM-1

2             TRNUM-2  
..................................................
```

In the top data tid,transactionnumber are two columns and the below are two rows data

next time i generate transaction number like i get maximum of tid and i generate transaction number like TRNUM-3 at the time of saving of page itself

But when two persons are using application at same time  two users are getting the same value like 3 so two persons transaction numbers saved as TRNUM-3

so to avoid that which process i can follow.please can you reply fast my clients are waiting  to get this problem solved Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to have two separate columns to denote a unique row.  Stick to thy MySQL unique ID and just use that for your transaction number.  The `tid` should be used in the database for references and the human readable transaction can just be created on the PHP side however you wish.

Comment: I do know that sir but in my erp generating transaction number depends upon the previous data if two users access at same time they are getting same data and they are getting same transaction numbers in above example if two users access table they will get maximum tid as 2 and they will transaction number as trnum-3 so two entries will be saved with same number..

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to fix it.

1. Oracle Way - The ways its Implemented in Oracle R12 and Fusion Application

   - Use sequence generator but unfortunately thats not available in mySQL
2. another Way , using mySQL

   - Save the record and get the transaction id and then add a constant number to it and update the record    again with the transaction number